# Error "Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher" using ApproximateTime Policy

Tags: ros, message-filters, publisher, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I try to use the ApproximateTime Policy-Based Synchronizer to get the force and position data from a force sensor and NDI, the code is show here which imitated from #q297174, in this code, I try to use `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` to get force and position data in one topic and publish it in `callback`, but it reported a mistake when the code run. then I try to publish the topic of force and position separately. it still fail under same mistake:

```
[ INFO] [1555644883.009164946]: Synchronization successful [10.000000]
[FATAL] [1555644883.009201476]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h
    line = 102
    cond = false
    message = 
[FATAL] [1555644883.009213278]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher
[FATAL] [1555644883.009220410]: 

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

---

```
[ INFO] [1555646329.618371967]: Synchronization successful [10.000000]
[FATAL] [1555646329.618447480]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h
    line = 69
    cond = false
    message = 
[FATAL] [1555646329.618476584]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher
[FATAL] [1555646329.618495410]: 

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

---

and the code is show here:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped.h>       
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>  
#include "std_msgs/Float64.h"

using namespace message_filters;
//tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf2_broadcaster;
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

//ros::Publisher sensor_pub;
ros::Publisher sensor_pub1;
ros::Publisher sensor_pub2;

void callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStampedConstPtr& netft_data_msg, const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& targets);  

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_all_sensor_in_one");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  //ros::Publisher sensor_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::TransformStamped>("/sensor_together", 1000);
  ros::Publisher sensor_pub1 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped>("/sensor_ati", 1000);
  ros::Publisher sensor_pub2 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/sensor_ndi", 1000);

  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped> force_sub(nh, "/netft_data", 1);    
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray> pose_sub(nh, "/polaris_sensor/targets", 1);    
  //message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped, geometry_msgs::PoseArray> sync(force_sub, pose_sub, 2);       
  typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped, geometry_msgs::PoseArray> MySyncPolicy;
  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), force_sub, pose_sub);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));                   

  // sensor_pub.publish(sync);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}

void callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStampedConstPtr& netft_data_msg, const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& targets)  
{

  // static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf2_broadcaster;
  // geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

  transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  transformStamped.header.frame_id = "ts_frame";
  transformStamped.child_frame_id = "prism_frame";
  transformStamped.transform.translation.x = targets->poses[0].position.x;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.y = targets->poses[0].position.y;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.z = targets->poses[0].position.z;
  tf2::Quaternion q;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.x;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.y;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.z;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = targets->poses[0].orientation.w;

  //tf2_broadcaster.sendTransform(transformStamped);

  ROS_INFO("Synchronization successful [%f]", 10.00);//transformStamped.transform.rotation.z

  //sensor_pub.publish(transformStamped);
  sensor_pub1.publish(netft_data_msg);
  sensor_pub2.publish(targets);
}
```

I edit the code and read the data without using the publisher:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped.h>       
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>  
#include "std_msgs/Float64.h"

using namespace message_filters;

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

void callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStampedConstPtr& netft_data_msg, const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& targets); 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_all_sensor_in_one");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped> force_sub(nh, "/netft_data", 1);  
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray> pose_sub(nh, "/polaris_sensor/targets", 1);    
  typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped, geometry_msgs::PoseArray> MySyncPolicy;
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), force_sub, pose_sub);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));                 


  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}

void callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStampedConstPtr& netft_data_msg, const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& targets)  
{
  transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  transformStamped.header.frame_id = "ts_frame";
  transformStamped.child_frame_id = "prism_frame";
  transformStamped.transform.translation.x = targets->poses[0].position.x;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.y = targets->poses[0].position.y;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.z = targets->poses[0].position.z;
  tf2::Quaternion q;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.x;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.y;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = netft_data_msg->wrench.force.z;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = targets->poses[0].orientation.w;

  ROS_INFO("Synchronization successful [%f]", transformStamped.transform.rotation.z);//transformStamped.transform.rotation.z

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321440/error-%22call-to-publish()-on-an-invalid-publisher%22-using-approximatetime-policy/) by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this in your code:

```
//ros::Publisher sensor_pub;
ros::Publisher sensor_pub1;
ros::Publisher sensor_pub2;

[..]

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  [..]

  ros::Publisher sensor_pub1 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped>("/sensor_ati", 1000);
  ros::Publisher sensor_pub2 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/sensor_ndi", 1000);

  [..]
}
```

The issue here is that you first declare two variables in the global scope, but then never initialise them.

This is because the two lines in `main(..)` that `advertise(..)` the topics assign the result of `NodeHandle::advertise<..>(..)` to two *function scope* variables with the same name, causing `sensor_pub1` and `sensor_pub2` in the global scope to never be initialised.

Your `callback(..)` in the end tries to call `publish(..)` on the uninitialised `Publisher`, leading to the error you show (and which probably makes sense now: `Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-19**:
Please note that this is a C++ issue. Not a ROS problem.

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2019-04-19**:
thanks for your help, and I'm not very good at C++, I will learn more about it. now I try to directly read the data in callback and not use publisher, it works and I can get the data after Synchronize.

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2019-04-19**:
the reason I use publisher is that I want record the data after synchronizing, and now ( I re-edit the code) the use of `ROS_INFO` let can see the one line data of `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped`. but now I wonder if there are some better way to record the data in `callback`? Did ROS provide some good tools for these or I need use some C++ ways to record the data in `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` ?
Thank you again!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-19**:
You should change

```
ros::Publisher sensor_pub1 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped>("/sensor_ati", 1000);
ros::Publisher sensor_pub2 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/sensor_ndi", 1000);
```

to

```
sensor_pub1 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped>("/sensor_ati", 1000);
sensor_pub2 = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/sensor_ndi", 1000);
```

so that you use global variable instead of creating new local variable.

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2019-04-22**:
I change my code as your advice, it works! thank you very much!